# Favicon ?? A little more perhaps

Tags: html

I've browsed this site and google extensively and found not a thing on how to fix my favicon issues.  I've read tutorials and still nothing.  I think the issue becomes I dont fully understand exactly what a favicon is.  I do no understand how clearing the cache would help facilitate the situation.  So my question is can someone explain to me where a favicon is actually supposed to be located ?  Why would a visitor's computer contain a different version of the image ?  What actually is a favicon(other than the stupid tab image that wont display!)?? I hope this question isnt too noob...

Comment: You might kill cache by changing the name of the favicon file, or adding something like `?version=3` to the file name to trick the browser into downloading it again (assuming you use `<link>` for the favicon).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just the image that is on the tab. And just put it in the root.

Put this code in your `<head>`

```
<link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
```

Clearing your cache makes the browser "GET" the file/image again. Usually it stores it and updates periodically. Clearing the cache automatically makes the browser get the file again.

If someone's cache has it stored as a different version, they would need to clear their cache to get the new version.

Instal [WAMP](http://www.wampserver.com/en/) (for windows) or [MAMP](http://www.mamp.info/en/index.html) (for Mac) if you want to test locally. Those programs will allow you to make your computer a testing web server.

Also, the file needs to be either 16x16 or 32x32 pixels.

Comment: So it has to be already sent through FTP to get it to run ?

Comment: If you have not uploaded it via FTP(or however you do it) to your server, then you wont see it unless you viewing the files locally.

Comment: i have yet to upload it to a sever. I am still building it locally on my machine, and it will not show up, but some of the tips i've seen suggest it wont ever show up until ive uploaded through a server...

Comment: generally, you want to test on an actual web server. Install MAMP or WAMP and use your computer as a web server.

Comment: WAMP is for windows, MAMP is for Mac, FYI.

Answer (score 1):

A favicon is exactly that. A little image (I suppose it comes from 'favorite icon') that is shown on a browser window for the user to visually identify your website among other tabs.

Most browsers and most servers cache the content to avoid downloading the image twice.

Suppose this:

Browser A downloads your resource (favicon image) and creates a cache of it.

Next time the browser sees the link to the image, it will guess its the same image and won't download it again, until that cache is cleared.

Answer (score 0):

The file favicon.ico should be uploaded into the root directory on the server hosting your web page. Here you can get the details. http://www.thesitewizard.com/archive/favicon.shtml

Comment: So i have to already have a host for my site, and not just building it locally at the moment ?

Comment: So place your favicon.ico file on root directory, name of root directory vary server. Which hosting are you using?